# cant access you tube Api in android

Tags: android, youtube-api

i m using following code to access youtube but on run time it is giving "class not found exception" i already added all Jar's reqiured

```
    String developer_key="my Key";    

    @Override     
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)   
    {       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);         
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);   
            YouTubeService service = new YouTubeService( developer_key);                
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

It's no longer that simple.

You must first create your UX element (YouTubePlayerView, YouTubePlayerFragment, YouTubeStandalonePlayer, etc), then you send the initialize message to it.

From the YouTube Android API Demo App PlayerViewDemoActivity.java:

```
/**
 * A simple YouTube Android API demo application which shows how to create a simple application that
 * displays a YouTube Video in a {@link YouTubePlayerView}.
 * <p>
 * Note, to use a {@link YouTubePlayerView}, your activity must extend {@link YouTubeBaseActivity}.
 */
public class PlayerViewDemoActivity extends YouTubeFailureRecoveryActivity {

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.playerview_demo);

    YouTubePlayerView youTubeView = (YouTubePlayerView) findViewById(R.id.youtube_view);
    youTubeView.initialize(DeveloperKey.DEVELOPER_KEY, this);
  }

  @Override
  public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer player,
      boolean wasRestored) {
    if (!wasRestored) {
      player.loadVideo("wKJ9KzGQq0w");
    }
  }

  @Override
  protected YouTubePlayer.Provider getYouTubePlayerProvider() {
    return (YouTubePlayerView) findViewById(R.id.youtube_view);
  }

}
```

From YouTubeFailureRecoveryActivity.java:

```
/**
 * An abstract activity which deals with recovering from errors which may occur during API
 * initialization, but can be corrected through user action.
 */
public abstract class YouTubeFailureRecoveryActivity extends YouTubeBaseActivity implements
    YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener {

  private static final int RECOVERY_DIALOG_REQUEST = 1;

  @Override
  public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider,
      YouTubeInitializationResult errorReason) {
    if (errorReason.isUserRecoverableError()) {
      errorReason.getErrorDialog(this, RECOVERY_DIALOG_REQUEST).show();
    } else {
      String errorMessage = String.format(getString(R.string.error_player), errorReason.toString());
      Toast.makeText(this, errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
  }

  @Override
  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == RECOVERY_DIALOG_REQUEST) {
      // Retry initialization if user performed a recovery action
      getYouTubePlayerProvider().initialize(DeveloperKey.DEVELOPER_KEY, this);
    }
  }

  protected abstract YouTubePlayer.Provider getYouTubePlayerProvider();

}
```